# Flexbox + z-index

Tags: css, css3, flexbox, less, z-index

Есть зелёный бокс-родитель с настройками:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: stretch;
```

В нём находятся 7 зелёных `radio` с плавающими/летающими размерами, называйте как хотите (14% от ширины родительского).

Нужно добавить по верх них ещё пару штук `radio` которые будут накладываться на них сверху с размерами (7% от ширины родительского и 2/3 высоты от зелёных) при этом, чтобы не смещались зелёные. Варианты с точными размерами не предлагать, только относительные в %.

```
<div class="octave-box">
  <div class="white-note"></div>
  <div class="black-note"></div>
  <div class="white-note"></div>
  <div class="black-note"></div>
  <div class="white-note"></div>
  <div class="white-note"></div>
  <div class="black-note"></div>
  <div class="white-note"></div>
  <div class="black-note"></div>
  <div class="white-note"></div>
  <div class="black-note"></div>
  <div class="white-note"></div>
</div>
```

!При этом чтобы между чёрными был пробел, и если на него кликнуть - работал нижний зелёный.

Вот LESS код:

```
.octave-box{
    .bgcl_cl(@red, @white);
    .bd_color(@grey);
    .margin_ALL;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    min-width: 30%;
    max-width: 30%;
    min-height: 98%;
    max-height: 98%;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще проблем не вижу. И штук 5 способов это сделать. И где код?

Comment: И хоть один способ как выглядит? Хоть примерно

Comment: transform translate, pointer-events:none, margin, width...

Comment: Видимо Вы не поняли вопроса, проблема в том, что при добавлении объектов, они сдвигают нижние 7шт основных... Вот я и спрашиваю, как сделать так, чтобы объект черного цвета не занимал площади (не брал её от зелёных и не выталкивал их за пределы родителя) относительно всего родительского div и был поверх остальных 7 зелёных объектов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.over {
  flex: 0 0 0px;
}

.over span {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 66.667%;
  width: 9%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

label:hover, label:hover span {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label class=over><span><input type=radio name=rbtn></span></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label class=over><span><input type=radio name=rbtn></span></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
</div>
```

Ещё можно вспомнить о свойстве order:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.over {
  flex: 0 0 0px;
}

.over span {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 66.667%;
  width: 9%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

label:hover, label:hover span {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label style=order:1><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label style=order:2><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label style=order:3><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label style=order:4><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label style=order:5><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label style=order:6><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label style=order:7><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label class=over style=order:1><span><input type=radio name=rbtn></span></label>
  <label class=over style=order:2><span><input type=radio name=rbtn></span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пианино:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.main {
  position: absolute;
}

.over {
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0 7.143%;
  position: relative;
}

.over label {
  pointer-events: all;
  background: black;
  height: 66.667%;
  margin: 0 3% auto;
}

label:hover {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
[[[ Основной поток ]]]
<div class=main>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
</div>
<div class=over>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
</div>
[[[ Основной поток ]]]
```

Comment: А каким свойством можно изменять расположение (текста) и настройки radio в общем: <label><input type=radio name=rbtn>(Текст)</label>

Comment: @KostiantynSalnykov, во-первых, не понял, а во-вторых, это другой вопрос.

Comment: Я имел в виду настройки _label_ внутри которой _radio_. Выравнивание текста, выравнивание шарика radio, параметры при :checked, подобное

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 10em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

label {
  background: green;
  flex: 2 0 0px;
  height: 100%;
  order: -1;
}

input {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.splitter {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  order: -1;
}

.splitter ~ label {
  height: 66.667%;
  margin: auto 3% 0;
  background: black;
  order: 1;
  transform: translateY(-150%);
}

.splitter + label {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

label:last-child {
  margin-right: 10%;
}

label:hover {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
[[[ Основной поток ]]]
<div>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>

  <span class=splitter></span>

  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
  <label><input type=radio name=rbtn></label>
</div>
[[[ Основной поток ]]]
```